# Best way to validate a form with flutter provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need separate logic with UI.

I used the following example:

1. Use a class validation item to show a string value and error.

   ```
   class ValidationItem {
       final String value;
       final String error;

       ValidationItem(this.value, this.error);
   }
   ```
2. Use the next code for provider class.

   ```
   class SignupValidation with ChangeNotifier {

       ValidationItem _firstName = ValidationItem(null,null);

       // Getters
       ValidationItem get firstName => _firstName;

       bool get isValid {
           if (_firstName.value != null) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return false;
           }
       }

       // Setters
       void changeFirstName(String value) {
           if (value.length >= 3) {
               _firstName = ValidationItem(value, null);
           } else {
               _firstName = ValidationItem(null, "Must be at least 3 characters");
           }
           notifyListeners();
       }

       void submitData() {
           print("FirstName: ${firstName.value}");
       }
    }
   ```
3. Use the next widget to show text field and validate

   ```
    class Signup extends StatelessWidget {
        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            final validationService = Provider.of<SignupValidation>(context);
            return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    title: Text('Signup'),
                ),
                body: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                            TextField(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "First Name",
                                    errorText: validationService.firstName.error,
                                ),
                                onChanged: (String value) {
                                    validationService.changeFirstName(value);
                                },
                         ),
                         RaisedButton( 
                             child: Text('Submit'),
                             onPressed: (!validationService.isValid) ? null : validationService.submitData,
                         )
                     ],
                  ),
              ),
           );
        }
    }
   ```

The problem is the performance for example every time the text is changed the `notifyListener()` is called.

My question: is there a cost to performance?

Answer (score 0):

you can use TextFormField instead of TextField.
Best way to validate fields is that you can use validator property TextFormField property as bellow

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "First Name",
  errorText: validationService.firstName.error,
  ),
  validator: (e){
    if(e!.trim().isEmpty) return "String is empty";
    return null;
  },
  onChanged: (String value) {
      validationService.changeFirstName(value);
  },
```

),

Comment: Thanks, but I need to separate the logic from the UI. If use validator the logic mixes with the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The TextField itself gives you the ability to validate the form, then why to make it complex by implementing notifier, instead you want to make it common you can make the validater global function for it. Nad user it in the validate function.

```
Void validateEmail(String value){ // your logic}
```

Use this function as follow

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  labelText: "First Name",
  errorText: validationService.firstName.error,
  ),
  validator: validateEmail(),
  onChanged: (String value) {
      validationService.changeFirstName(value);
  },
```

Secondly to get the value of inputted string you have a TextEditingController which directly give you the string you inputted.

Declare TextEditingController as follow

```
TextEditingController emailCont = TextEditingController();
```

Use this controller in TextField as follow

```
TextFormField(
      controller: emailCont,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: "First Name",
      errorText: validationService.firstName.error,
      ),
      validator: validateEmail(),
      onChanged: (String value) {
          validationService.changeFirstName(value);
      },
```

Now to get the value from this controller you can get it this way.

```
emailCont.text
```

This way it will be easy to manage and less complexity.